# Manipulating List in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a small tagging script in Python(2.x). 
I am trying to tag each line of a corpus with a dictionary. 
The script is generally behaving fine, but I am looking for slight different 
result.

The code is like,

```
def tag_corpus():
    corpus1=open("Corpus1.txt","r")
    dict1=open("Dictnew1.txt","r")
    dictw=dict1.read().lower().split()
    list1=[]
    for line in corpus1:
        linew=line.lower().split()
        for word in linew:
            if word in dictw:
                word_i=dictw.index(word)
                word_i1=word_i+1
                tag=dictw[word_i1]
                str1=word+"/"+tag
                list1.append(str1)
            else:
                str2=word+"/"+"NA"
                list1.append(str2)
    str3=" ".join(list1)
    print str3
```

Where the contents of "Corpus1.txt" is,

```
  London is situtated over Thames . 
  London is a village near Burgundy . 
  London is situated near Ontario .
```

and of "Dictnew1.txt" is,

London LOC 
  Thames LOC
  Burgundy LOC 
  Ontario LOC

The result is coming as,

```
london/loc is/NA situtated/NA over/NA thames/loc ./NA london/loc is/NA a/NA village/NA near/NA burgundy/loc ./NA london/loc is/NA situated/NA near/NA ontario/loc ./NA
```

But I am looking for a output of tagged string as it is printing out the string,
like

```
london is situtated over thames .
  london/loc is/NA situtated/NA over/NA thames/loc .
```

If any one may kindly suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Does this produce the output you expect?

```
def tag_corpus():
    corpus1=open("Corpus1.txt","r")
    dict1=open("Dictnew1.txt","r")
    dictw=dict1.read().lower().split()
    for line in corpus1:
        list1=[]
        linew=line.lower().split()
        for word in linew:
            if word in dictw:
                word_i=dictw.index(word)
                word_i1=word_i+1
                tag=dictw[word_i1]
                str1=word+"/"+tag
                list1.append(str1)
            else:
                str2=word+"/"+"NA"
                list1.append(str2)
        str3=" ".join(list1)
        print line
        print str3
```

Comment: Looks fine. I was wondering how it may come and did many experiments. Just Thanks.